# With mongoTemplate, how can you form the criteria on a reference collection?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have three tables in my mongo database as below,

```
Operation {
        
        @Id
        String id;
        
        @Field("name")
        String name;
    }

File {
        
        @Id
        String id;
        
        @Field("name")
        String name;
        
        @Field("type")
        FileType type; //enum

        @DBRef
        @Field("operation")
        private Operation operation;
    }

Report {
    
        @Id
        String id;
    
        @Field("name")
        String name;
    
        @Field("generated_date")
        LocalDate generatedDate;
        
        @DBRef
        @Field("file")
        private File file;

    }
```

I use mongoTemplate to filter reports based on its different fields. However as a new functionality I need to filter reports based on the operationId. Each report is associated to one File, and each file to one operation, but I am having trouble to create a critera or aggregation that will help me to the same.

Initially I tried something like this where,

1)
Here we create a list of criterias,

```
List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
criteriaList.add(Criteria.where("generated_date").is("2023-05-12");
criteriaList.add(Criteria.where("file.operation.$id").is(createObjectIdFromString(client.getId()))
);
return new Criteria().andOperator(criteriaList);
```

This criteriaList is passed to the MatchOperation

```
MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(criteria);
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation);
AggregationResults<Report> missions = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "report", Report.class);
```

But this returns no results.

2)
Another attempt I tried was to lookup and unwind before matching the operation

```
List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
criteriaList.add(Criteria.where("generated_date").is("2023-05-12");
criteriaList.add(Criteria.where("_file.operation.$id").is(createObjectIdFromString(client.getId()))
);
return new Criteria().andOperator(criteriaList);


 LookupOperation lookupOperation = Aggregation.lookup("file","file.$id","_id", "_file");
 UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("$_file");
 MatchOperation matchOperation1 = Aggregation.match(operationCriteria);
 Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation, unwindOperation);
 AggregationResults<Report> missions = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation1, "report", Report.class);
```

But this returns no results either.

If anyone could help me see what I'm missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this issue with this,

```
Aggregation.addFields().addField("fileId").withValue("$file.$id").build();
Aggregation.lookup("file", "fileId", "_id", "_file");
Aggregation.unwind("$_file");
Aggregation.match(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_file.operation.$id").is("id"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).